# Unit testing rendered Json with JsonBuilder in Grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, render, jsonbuilder

Let's say I have a simple action in my controller that ends with:

```
render(contentType: "text/json") {
    message = 'some text'
    foo = 'bar'
}
```

It renders correctly, as per the JSON builder [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#moreOnJSONBuilder).  However, when I attempt to unit test that response in a ControllerUnitTest, I get a blank string with `controller.response.contentAsString`.  I even tried `controller.renderArgs`, but that just contains `contentType: "text/json"`.

When I convert the JSON to a map, and marshall it `as JSON`, then I can test properly.  But is there a way to unit test the code as it stands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, I found that this is not possible in 1.3.7.  Either have to upgrade to Grails 2.0, or override the controller metaClass as suggested in [this post](http://www.lucasward.net/2011/03/grails-testing-issue-when-rendering-as.html):

```
controller.class.metaClass.render = { Map map, Closure c ->
    renderArgs.putAll(map)

    switch(map["contentType"]) {
        case null:
            break

        case "application/xml":
        case "text/xml":
            def b = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
            if (map["encoding"]) b.encoding = map["encoding"]

            def writable = b.bind(c)
            delegate.response.outputStream << writable
            break

        case "text/json":
            new JSonBuilder(delegate.response).json(c)
            break
        default:
            println "Nothing"
            break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the action in your tests and compare the results using controller.response.contentAsString

so your test method would look like

```
void testSomeRender() {
controller.someRender()
assertEquals "jsonString", controller.response.contentAsString

}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but like I mentioned, I just get a blank string (or it contains "contentType: 'text/json'", I can't remember off the top of my head)

Comment: I just added a code for an action which return the JSON string like you are trying to do and I don't see any content. So the issue is with content not being rendered. What version of Grails are you using ?

Comment: 1.3.7, I know 2.0 has better support, but unfortunately I can't switch to that. :-\

Comment: 1.3.7 is a stable release than 2.0. 2.3 wasn't suppose to be out till oct and they are already out with the bug fixes. I think that the JSON convertor doesn't convert any String objects to JSON and hence its returning empty string. One thing which I tried was created a Expando Object and added properties to it and then rendered it and it worked. I think you should try that. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post http://www.lucasward.net/2011/03/grails-testing-issue-when-rendering-as.html

Comment: Broken link, 404.